# Ionic custom font

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, fonts

Greetings and I turn to you with a question about the font.

Edit: This app is for the mobile devices (ios, android) in Ionic with Angular.

I want to use Poppins font in an application. When running on a PC - windows in a browser like Google Chrome etc ... so everything works perfectly.

But as soon as I try to run the application on a Mac, an iPhone emulator or on a real device - iPhone 11. The fonts will not be loaded at all.

Can someone advise me on what my mistake is or what I'm doing wrong. No one around me has encountered a similar case.

I will attach the code as I import the fonts + their subsequent use.

fonts.scss

```
/* poppins-300 - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins-light';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-300.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local(''), url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        /* IE6-IE8 */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-300.woff2') format('woff2'),
        /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-300.woff') format('woff'),
        /* Modern Browsers */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-300.ttf') format('truetype'),
        /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-300.svg#Poppins') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
/* poppins-regular - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins-medium';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local(''), url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        /* IE6-IE8 */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
        /* Modern Browsers */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-regular.svg#Poppins') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
/* poppins-italic - latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins-italic';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local(''), url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        /* IE6-IE8 */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
        /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-italic.woff') format('woff'),
        /* Modern Browsers */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
        /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('../assets/fonts/poppins-v15-latin-italic.svg#Poppins') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

global.scss - for creating a class with that custom font

```
.font-light {
    font-family: Poppins-light;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have import this in scss file

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
```

And how use this

```css
ion-title {
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: ion-title {  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; }